# Recurring task processing 80k tasks stored in DynamoDB every 30 minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I have been looking into ways to implement a recurring task for processing large number of items stored in dynamoDB. After doing some research online, one of the options involves using CloudWatch Events to trigger an event every 30 mins, the event then triggers lambda A, lambda then reads all of the items, publish them to SQS and have multiple instances of lambda B consume from SQS and process them in parallel. (processing will take ~200ms)

But the problem is lambda has 15 mins limit and reading all 80k tasks from DynamoDB at once does not seem feasible.

Would anyone be able to offer suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Is it statefull processing? if stateless you should have multiple lambdas to build your processing logic.

Answer (score 2):

If an AWS Lambda function takes too long to run, you could instead **launch an Amazon EC2 instance with a User Data startup script** to perform a similar function. Once it has completed its task, it could self-terminate. (Set `Startup Behavior = Terminate`, then just issue a Shutdown command to the Operating System.)

However, you are saying that this task needs to be done every 30 minutes, but the Lambda function might take longer than 15 minutes to push everything to SQS. This might justify **simply running a small EC2 instance at all times**, rather than firing-up a Lambda function every 30 minutes. The EC2 instance could use a cron job to trigger the activities. Pricing would be similar (~1c/hour).

Another bottleneck might be the reading of 80K items every 30 minutes, which would cause spikes in the access pattern for DynamoDB. (Lots of usage for a short period every 30 minutes). This might require **over-provisioning of read capacity** to ensure it can meet the demand.

Comment: Thanks for the proposed solution! (I will definitely take this into account.) I am also looking into utilizing DynamoDB TTL to expire (and delete) an item, which emits an event consumed by SQS. Problem with this implementation is that there is a potential delay up to 48 hours depending on the size of the table. Based on this [analysis](https://medium.com/@michabahr/analysis-of-dynamodbs-ttl-delay-de878e2c6d47) it seems for 100k items, the max delay is around 27 mins.

Answer (score 1):

@john-rotenstein shared a solution for long running job, I would personally choose it as accepted one :-)
My answer will be a small reframing of your problem state.

If triggering Lambda every 30 minutes leads to long Lambda execution due to big number of tasks, then reduce the load for single Lambda.
For example:

1. Trigger Lambda more frequently (e.g. every minute).
2. Trigger several Lambdas with smaller batch of tasks.

By the way I assume you read from DynamoDB in batches.